# Why does my Windows 8 Pro Hyper-V guest have no internet?

Tags: virtualization, windows-8, hyper-v

Trying to get this working on my Windows 8 Pro machine. I created an External Switch

Assigned the newly available adapter to a Guest machine with Win 2008 os. My host has internet connection. Host can ping Guest, Guest cannot ping Host.

Guest has no internet connection. Pasting the IP of both host and guest.

```
HOST
==========================
Ethernet adapter vEthernet (EXTSW01):
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter #2
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 9C-B7-0F-0F-D7-D0
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::5434:a9fd:8611:d207%54(Preferred) 
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.15(Preferred) 
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Saturday, September 8, 2012 12:34:44 PM
Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Saturday, September 15, 2012 12:34:44 PM
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 916240141
DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-17-DC-C9-2C-9C-B7-0D-0D-D7-D0
DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 64.71.255.999
NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

---

```
GUEST
==========================
Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Virtual Machine Bus Network Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-15-5D-3F-0F-00
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::953f:ec5c:5d84:1b50%11(Preferred) 
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.20(Preferred) 
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 0.0.0.0
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 234886493
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-17-DD-2F-29-0F-15-5E-00-0F-00
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : ::1
   127.0.0.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had issues similar to this. It seemed to be caused by having other virtualization software (Virtualbox) installed along with Hyper-V. You could check the properties -> sharing tab of the vEthernet adapter and try setting it to share internet. I still had intermittent internet issues with this setup though.

I ended up uninstalling Virtualbox to get Hyper-V working solid.

Edit:
https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=48044

Answer (score 0):

Dont forget to activate the Virtual LAN ID which you can find in the Guest settings of the Hyper-V-Manager!

[image]